# Any scientific evidence that consumption of the placenta is nutrious for a new mother? Does it prevent postpartum depression?

Tags: fetus, placenta, postpartum-depression, oxytocin

From what I understand, consumption of the placenta (placentophagy) either via capsule or actual eating, has become more common (although I believe it is still a fringe practice). I know that other mammals have been doing this after giving birth, but is there any scientific evidence that it benefits a human mother? I have read both those that say there are benefits and those that say there is no benefits so I'm confused.

I read that the possible benefits are that the placenta is obviously chalkful of vitamins and hormones that will help the mother to heal both physically and emotionally after giving birth. For instance, it could help prevent postpartum-depression? It contains oxytocin, which helps promote lactation for breastfeeding? It contains prostaglandin, which helps the uterus to revert back as much as possible to its smaller state?

But then I read that there is no evidence that it does either of these, and it's possibly just a placebo effect. That the placenta only benefited the fetus while in the womb.

I'm not pregnant or anything, I would just like to better understand this trend, and know the science behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure its been well-known among females that eating the placenta has lots of health benefits, but recent [studies](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~kristal/placentophagia%20review.pdf) has shown that it doesn't.

[Meredith Carlson Daly](https://www.nichd.nih.gov/news/releases/Pages/062615-podcast-placenta-consumption.aspx) studied this and commented saying;

"Researchers at Northwestern University School of Medicine reviewed 10 published research studies on the practice of placentophagy.  They found no data to support the common claims that eating the placenta either raw, cooked, or encapsulated offers protection against postpartum depression, reduces post-delivery pain, boosts energy, helps with lactation, promotes skin elasticity, enhances maternal bonding, or replenishes iron in the body.  The researchers also noted that there have been no studies conducted on whether eating the placenta has any potential risks."

While no scientific study has proven any benefits, a survey was conducted by American Medical anthropologists at the University of South Florida and University of Nevada, Las Vegas. Among the respondents, about 3/4 claimed to have positive experiences from eating their own placenta, citing "improved mood", "increased energy", and "improved lactation"